# What is this tool with a notch at the end of a shaft?

Tags: tools, hand-tools

It’s made of a single piece of steel or a steel alloy, has a handle and shaft with a notch at the end of the shaft. I tried a google search and even a google image search using the photo below but couldn’t find it.

It is 5.5 inches (14cm) long.

What is this tool called and what is it used for?

[image]

Comment: It’s about 5 - 1/2 inches, or 14cm.

Comment: someone may have made it in a high school metalshop class

Comment: Context of where you found it or got it.  Looks like a plug follower someone made (used when removing a lock core) to keep pins and springs in the Bible. Or it looks like a custom made tamper proof spanner screwdriver.

Comment: the knurled handle suggests a tool for a greasy environment

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It could be used for any of the following, depending on size:

- A [Schrader valve core](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schrader_valve) tool, used for automotive tires (see [examples](https://www.amazon.com/slp/schrader-valve-tool/7qocfkzsav8v4v8))
- A wing-nut tool, useful in tight places or to apply more force
- A [wire-wrap tool](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=wire%20wrap%20tool&ref=nb_sb_noss_1), if there is a recess at the end of the shaft
- A tool for hand-bending metal contacts or light wire

Comment: It is a Shrader valve core tool.  I found the model on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/ProTool-Professional-Valve-Removal-Silver/dp/B003YXDJO4/ref=sr_1_33?keywords=schrader+valve+core+tool&qid=1577392611&sr=8-33).

Answer (score 2):

It looks like a broken breaker bar with the end ground down for some specialty job. They are manufactured by many companies but here's a similar piece about the same size or it could be a larger one cut down.
[image]

Comment: It’s probably not a breaker bar given it’s length of 5.5 inches. I added the length to my question.

Comment: I agree, breaker bars are usually way BIGGER than your hand. 5 - 6 inches is not going to give you extra leverage over a 5 - 6 inch wrench or socket.

Comment: It could definitely be a breaker bar, they come in all sizes. Look at the picture in the answer, that **is** a breaker bar. **+1**

Comment: Good guess but as it turns out, it's a Schrader valve core tool.  Breaker bars can come in that -length-, but the shaft diameter on the tool in question is much smaller than this breaker bar.